# Insert Error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to insert from code behind on an asp.net form,

I have two tables:
Table Trainings
training_id
training_Date
.
.

Table personTraining
id
training_id
name,
dept

Am I doing something wrong?

I need to insert the values from the form , plus, select the values from a lookup table , where the training id is equal to dropdown selected value .

```
private void InsertInfo()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string sql = "INSERT INTO personTraining (name,training_id,training,trainingDate.trainingHour,trainingSession)  VALUES (@Val1,SELECT (training_id,training,trainingDate.trainingHour,trainingSession FROM tbl_training WHERE training_id = dpDate.selectedValue))";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", txtName.Text);
//will add rest of form fields

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use something like

```
INSERT INTO personTraining
            (name,
             training_id,
             training,
             trainingDate.trainingHour,
             trainingSession)
SELECT @Val1,
       training_id,
       training,
       trainingDate.trainingHour,
       trainingSession
FROM   tbl_training
WHERE  training_id = dpDate.selectedValue
```

You can't have a hybrid `VALUES` clause/`SELECT` statement like that.

Comment: thanks , I have one more question , the only thing error is to pass the selected value from dropdown as a parameter to query the trainings table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO personTraining (
    name,
    training_id,
    training,
    trainingDate.trainingHour,
    trainingSession)  
SELECT 
    @Val1,
    training_id,
    training,
    trainingDate.trainingHour,
    trainingSession 
FROM tbl_training tt 
WHERE training_id = dpDate.selectedValue
```